Did 60 Minutes edit one of Kamala Harris' interview answers?
This 9GAG post alleges that Kamala Harris gave an incoherent "word salad" answer during a recent 60 Minutes interview, and that 60 Minutes edited the answer into something more coherent. 9GAG heading:

60 Minutes caught deleting interview footages and replacing with heavily edited videos.

Top rated comments claim that (1) both answers were "complete gibberish" or (2) "word salad"



Original answer began with:

Well, Bill, the work that we have done has resulted in a number of movements in that region by Israel that were very much prompted by, or a result of, many things, including our advocacy for what needs to happen in the region.

Edited answer jumps to a different sentence:

We are not going to stop pursuing what is necessary for the United States to be clear about where we stand on the need for this war to end.

I'd like the truth about this particular incident. Is the alleged footage of Kamala's "actual answer" authentic, and was it actually edited by 60 Minutes into the "edited answer" footage that was aired?

Comments have extended past improving the question, and have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Both edits were released by 60 Minutes
According to Variety:

In a teaser clip released online, which also aired on “Face the Nation” on Oct. 6, Harris provided a lengthy response to “60 Minutes” correspondent Bill Whitaker’s question about whether the U.S. lacks influence over Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu. In the final interview that aired Oct. 7, Harris’ answer was edited differently.

And that seems to be the extent of what's publicly known, with little primary information:

In a statement addressing the controversy surrounding the edited response, an aide for the Harris campaign told Variety, “We do not control CBS’s production decisions and refer questions to CBS.”
CBS did not immediately respond to Variety‘s request for comment.

While it's expected that some editing must occur with recorded interviews for length and clarity, this is not the first time 60 Minutes has faced this type of criticism. In 2018, they were criticized for their edits of Elon Musk's answers. See for example Ars, which quotes both 60 Minutes and a transcript they got from Tesla with longer answers.

Are they under the impression that people wouldn't notice? Do they believe us to be this dumb?

@Phil It's CBS.

CBS did comment now (via AP):

After the differences were pointed out online, Trump said on his Truth Social feed that Harris’ “REAL ANSWER WAS CRAZY, OR DUMB, so they actually REPLACED it with another answer in order to save her or, at least, to make her look better.”
So what did Harris actually say to Whitaker?
Well, both things, according to CBS. Her full answer to the question was the two sentences put together — the first sentence used on “Face the Nation” and the second sentence on “60 Minutes.”
CBS said the need to make the “60 Minutes” interview segment concise prompted the editing. The full interview with Harris took 45 minutes, and it was fit into a 20-minute slot on the broadcast. Yet the editing made it appear that the answer shown on “60 Minutes” was the first thing Harris said in response to the question. Having “Face the Nation” show Whitaker asking the question — instead of having someone paraphrase it — added to the confusion and made CBS vulnerable to criticism.
The network would not respond to Trump’s criticisms on the record but privately insisted nothing was done with the intention of benefiting Harris. The network has pointed out that the same process was in place when Trump was interviewed for the show several times earlier.

Also

Two, not just one, interview answers were edited differently
According to an examination of the broadcasts, the same thing happened with the question that preceded Whitaker’s observation that the Israeli leader did not appear to be listening to the U.S. Whitaker outlined a number of actions that Netanyahu had taken that the Biden administration had urged him not to, and asked, “Does the administration have no sway over Prime Minister Netanyahu?”
On “60 Minutes,” Harris’ answer was brief: “The work that we do diplomatically with the leadership of Israel is an ongoing pursuit around making clear our principles.”
Yet on “Face the Nation,” Harris was shown giving an answer that lasted a full minute — and did not even include the quote that was used on “60 Minutes” the next night. As part of that answer, Harris spoke of efforts to achieve a ceasefire and the release of hostages held by Hamas. “We’re not going to stop in terms of putting the pressure on Israel and in the region, including Arab leaders,” she said.

So it seems to be part of how CBS uses the same interview raw material to make two shows.
FWTW, the piece ends by mentioning that (conversely) some of the press has been accused of "sanewashing" Trump.
